# How does MySQL optimizer compute join cost when indexed?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

So, The standard formula in theory is

> C(R1.R2) = C(R1) + T(R1)*C(R2) where,
>
> C(R1.R2) - Cost of joining two relations (tables) R1 and R2
>
> C(R1) - Cost of reading relation R1
>
> C(R2) - Cost of reading relation R2
>
> T(R1) - Total number of rows in R1

It seems like this is the formula for Nested Loop Join, when for every row in relation `R1` and the loop checks for matching row in relation `R2`. But since MySQL builds index for FK, It need not do NLJ right? What happens and how is the cost calculated?

Comment: MySQL almost always does NLJ; unless it decides to BNL (Block Nested Loop) Optimization. MySQL 8+ has introduced Hash Joins for non-indexed columns with equality comparison

Comment: Some details may be viewed in [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  The Optimizer Cost Model](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cost-model.html). There exists `key_compare_cost` value.